# Using wget with windows command prompt to download the files outside the site directory

Tags: windows, wget

I have to download files which are outside the my site directory using `wget` with windows let me make it more clear.

I have my site running on Linux server.

```
Domain  ---> www.example.com

/var/www/html ---> This is the my site directory

/home/username/data.csv  ---> This is the file I wants to download
```

When I try to download any file from the site directory it is working fine but it is not getting downloaded from here `/home/username/data.csv`

```
c:\wget\ wget.exe --ftp-user="username" --ftp-password="password" "www.example.com/index.php"
```

The above command works good and '`index.php`' file is downloaded successfully.

But how to target `/home/username/data.csv` file and download using `wget`?

I tried with this but I was sure this will not work.

```
c:\wget\ wget.exe --ftp-user="username" --ftp-password="password" "www.example.com/home/username/data.csv"
```

I can understand why this command does not work and return `404 error`, because the domain is pointing to the `/var/www/html` directory hence `wget` internally reads it like `/var/www/html/home/username/data.csv` and this is true there is no such file.

So my question is Does `wget` accept the path?

How do I do download the file outside my site directory?

Comment: just looking at the jist, how about  -H,  to span hosts

Comment: oh i see what you're asking, no you cannot obviously. It's simply not on the web or ftp server. though you could start another one on that directory. but ssh will let you copy any file from the terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **How do I do download the file outside my site directory?**

You can't ask the web server to provide it, for security reasons.

Try using ftp instead

```
wget ftp://username:password@www.example.com/data.csv
```

If FTP service isn't available, configure it or use `sftp` instead, for greater security.

Comment: FTP service is not configured and I tried with SFTP `wget sftp://username:password@www.example.com/data.csv` but it says `Unsupported Scheme`

Comment: wget doesn't support sftp, there is a separate client program. For Windows you can use WinSCP or Putty's sftp. However you should first check that there is an sshd and sftpd service running on the server and you may need to set up some authentication credentials depending on how the server is configured. How do you upload files to the web-server?

Answer (score 0):

Your web server is only serving files from the `/var/www/html/` path and it doesn't know about the existence of `/home/username/`. You need to launch some kind of a web server instance inside `/home/username/` before you can `wget` files from that directory.

Here are a couple of ways to make that work.

---

- Start a temporary HTTP server instance using Python in your home directory.

`$ cd /home/username`

`$ python -m SimpleHTTPServer` (`python -m http.server` on `Python 3.x`)

`$ wget http://example.com:8000/data.csv`

---

- Create a symlink to `/home/username/` from `/var/www/html/`, though this is not recommended as it exposes your entire home directory. Or create the symlink to `data.csv` itself.

`$ cd /var/www/html/`

`$ ln -s /home/username/data.csv data.csv` (`ln -s /home/username homedir` to symlink the directory)

`$ wget http://www.example.com/data.csv`

Make sure, that you have enabled using symlinks (globally or for this Directory only) `Options FollowSymLinks` 
See [here](http://uw714doc.sco.com/en/FD_files/Getting_to_a_file.html) for more documentation regarding symbolic links.

---

Comment: okay will give a try

Comment: Thanks, I did not tried this way but i think this should work. I did this with `WinScp`.